# NTLM Authentication - after authenticated, is there any token issued by server?

Tags: ntlm

After NTLM authenticated, does the server issue some kind of token to client, then next time client requests the resources on the same server, then it will ignore the NTML authenticate process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After authentication there is a sealing key and possibly a signing key created from the base key generated in the authentication. These are used for the rest of the session. The authenticate process occurs only once per session as can be seen [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236629.aspx)

The [protocol details page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236655.aspx) explains the entire process in further detail.

Comment: (From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236701.aspx) In connectionless mode, messages can arrive out of order. Because of this, the sealing key MUST be reset for every message.

Comment: So in connection mode, means sealing key is reused, is that mean, if a middle-man have the sealing key, then he/she can fake the server?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that if the sealing key is compromised then the attacker can send messages to the server pretending to be the valid client, as if this security is used the sealing is treated as implicit signing as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236707.aspx). Note however that the purpose of this protocol is to make MitM attacks harder. A MitM attack with enough resources can compromise any mutual authentication along a un-secure channel, and guarding against it requires a secure channel. Fully explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: I have difficulties to understand the use of this key, is this the same characteristic than and access_token in Oauth2 ? @CharlesB.